# which JSON schema to use for jquery in c#

Tags: jquery, json, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am new to JSON and have never used it before in c#/.Net.

i am trying to link a JSON file to an existing SQL in my MVC project. 
I have read up different things and have searched this site for all answers but couldn't find one yet. 
I am not in a school and everything I know about Json and SQL is through research. I'm STILL self learning and ask for anyone's help.

My end goal is to have in the Json file a `get`and `post`,. to have a callback.

1) I created a Json file in Model but don't know which Schema to use. MVC gives me loads of options. Ideally, I would like to use JQuery, which i am a bit familiar with

2) once I pass this stage, how to I get it to link to my SQL, which I have created using ADO.Net and named it .edmx. (Perhps I didn't need to name it .edmx, as I don't see any difference if it has this identifier).

Please don't just mark me as irrelevant and help a novice get into this exciting field

I have used MSSMS to get two tables and a third that combines the two. 
I have created a blank controller and a blank View. The only code that I have for now is the SQL which I have copied and executed in ADO. Here is the SQL code:

```
> > USE Master GO
> 
> IF EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name =
> N'TechTest') BEGIN    DROP DATABASE [TechTest] END GO
> 
> IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name =
> N'TechTest') BEGIN    CREATE DATABASE [TechTest] END GO
> 
> USE [TechTest] GO
> 
> /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Colours]    Script Date: 09/04/2014
> 13:58:02 ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colours](     [ColourId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT
> NULL,     [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,     [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL, 
> CONSTRAINT [PK_Colours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (  [ColourId] ASC )WITH
> (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
> ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON
> [PRIMARY]
> 
> GO /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[FavouriteColours]    Script Date:
> 09/04/2014 13:58:02 ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER
> ON GO CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FavouriteColours](  [PersonId] [int] NOT
> NULL,     [ColourId] [int] NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT [PK_FavouriteColours]
> PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (  [PersonId] ASC,     [ColourId] ASC )WITH
> (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
> ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON
> [PRIMARY]
> 
> GO /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[People]    Script Date: 09/04/2014
> 13:58:02 ******/ SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[People](  [PersonId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
>   [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT
> NULL,     [IsAuthorised] [bit] NOT NULL,  [IsValid] [bit] NOT NULL,
>   [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT [PK_People] PRIMARY KEY
> CLUSTERED  (  [PersonId] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,
> STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS =
> ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
> 
> GO SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Colours] ON 
> 
> GO INSERT [dbo].[Colours] ([ColourId], [Name], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (1,
> N'Red', 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[Colours] ([ColourId], [Name], [IsEnabled])
> VALUES (2, N'Green', 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[Colours] ([ColourId], [Name],
> [IsEnabled]) VALUES (3, N'Blue', 1) GO SET IDENTITY_INSERT
> [dbo].[Colours] OFF GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId],
> [ColourId]) VALUES (1, 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours]
> ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (1, 2) GO INSERT
> [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (1, 3) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (2, 1)
> GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (2,
> 2) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES
> (2, 3) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId])
> VALUES (3, 2) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId],
> [ColourId]) VALUES (4, 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours]
> ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (4, 2) GO INSERT
> [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (4, 3) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (5, 2)
> GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (6,
> 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES
> (7, 2) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId])
> VALUES (7, 3) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId],
> [ColourId]) VALUES (8, 2) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours]
> ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (9, 1) GO INSERT
> [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (10, 1) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES (10,
> 2) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId]) VALUES
> (10, 3) GO INSERT [dbo].[FavouriteColours] ([PersonId], [ColourId])
> VALUES (11, 1) GO SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[People] ON  GO INSERT
> [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised],
> [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (1, N'Willis', N'Tibbs', 0, 1, 0) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName],
> [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (2, N'Sharon', N'Halt',
> 0, 0, 0) GO INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName],
> [LastName], [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (3,
> N'Patrick', N'Kerr', 0, 1, 1) GO INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId],
> [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled])
> VALUES (4, N'Lilly', N'Hale', 0, 0, 0) GO INSERT [dbo].[People]
> ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised], [IsValid],
> [IsEnabled]) VALUES (5, N'Joel', N'Daly', 0, 1, 1) GO INSERT
> [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised],
> [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (6, N'Imogen', N'Kent', 0, 0, 0) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName],
> [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (7, N'George',
> N'Edwards', 0, 1, 0) GO INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId],
> [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled])
> VALUES (8, N'Gabriel', N'Franics', 0, 0, 0) GO INSERT [dbo].[People]
> ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised], [IsValid],
> [IsEnabled]) VALUES (9, N'Courtney', N'Arnold', 0, 1, 1) GO INSERT
> [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName], [IsAuthorised],
> [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (10, N'Brian', N'Allen', 0, 1, 1) GO
> INSERT [dbo].[People] ([PersonId], [FirstName], [LastName],
> [IsAuthorised], [IsValid], [IsEnabled]) VALUES (11, N'Bo', N'Bob', 1,
> 1, 0) GO SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[People] OFF GO ALTER TABLE
> [dbo].[FavouriteColours]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT
> [FK_FavouriteColours_Colours] FOREIGN KEY([ColourId]) REFERENCES
> [dbo].[Colours] ([ColourId]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FavouriteColours]
> CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FavouriteColours_Colours] GO ALTER TABLE
> [dbo].[FavouriteColours]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT
> [FK_FavouriteColours_People] FOREIGN KEY([PersonId]) REFERENCES
> [dbo].[People] ([PersonId]) GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[FavouriteColours]
> CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_FavouriteColours_People] GO
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly , Show some code  which you have done or What is the desired Output you need using `c#` and `Jquery` ?

Comment: I have edited my question and included the SQL code

Comment: Ok , But still What are you trying do ? Do you want convert data from SQL Sever database to `Json`format and show in you web page using `Jquery` or Do you want save `Json` data in you `Sql` table ? Try to explain , so that others can guide you.

Comment: My end game is, i am trying to access the data through Json and reproduce it in HTML format

Answer (score 0):

**Pass data from Controller to view**

This show's how to Pass data from Controller to view , but to pass Pass `Json` data from Controller to view I have provided references to follow below.

**View Model**

```
public class PersonViewModel
{

  public int PersonId { get; set; }

  public string FirstName { get; set; }

  public string LastName { get; set; }

  public bool IsAuthorised { get; set; }

  public int ColourId { get; set; }

  public string ColourName { get; set; }

}
```

**Action Method**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
  {


// TODO, Get data from SQL database using ADO.NET or Entity Framework

Person personData = GetDataFromSQLServerRepository();

// Fill your view model

PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel();

model.FirstName  = personData.FirstName;
model.LastName   = personData.LastName ;
model.ColourName = personData.ColourName;

        return View(model);
 }
```

**Index View**

```
@model DemoProject.Models.PersonViewModel

<h1>Person Details</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Colour Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach(var person in Model)
    {
    <tr>
        <td>@person.FirstName</td>  
        <td>@person.LastName</td>  
        <td>@person.ColourName</td>  
    </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**For More Options:**

**Pass data from Controller to view**

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279547/how-to-display-database-records-in-asp-net-mvc-view)

[2.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/various-ways-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view-in-mvc/)

**Pass Json data from Controller to view**

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972656/returning-json-data-from-controller-to-view-asp-net-mvc)

[2.](http://www.compilemode.com/2016/09/display-json-data-from-controller-to-view-in-asp-net-mvc.html)

[3.](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3222/beginners-guide-to-underscorejs) - Using `underscorejs` for better templating.